# Calculate Future Due Date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Looking for suggestions on best way to calculate a future date that is based on a past date that repeats every X periods (EXAMPLE: Car payment was first due on 11/01/2018 and is due every 2 weeks.  What is the next due date that is equal to or greater than today?) or (EXAMPLE: Payment to BOB was first due on 11/01/2019 and is due every 10 days.  What is the next due date that is equal to or greater than today?)

[image: SCREENSHOT IMAGE OF EXCEL TABLE REFERENCED BELOW]

In the above screenshot - what I am trying to do is have a formula to calculate what the next due date will be and place that value in date format in cell H4, H5. The values have to be equal to or beyond today (IE: >=B1)

I assume the formula will use the Logical IF function but beyond that I am stumped.

Thank-You in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

The following formula should work:

```
=MAX(A1,TODAY()-MOD(TODAY()-A1,14)+14)
```

Where `A1` hold the first due date in the sequence, adjust the range to suit your needs

edit: modified formula to deal with first deadline in the future

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  It is not working in this case.  My table shows Column B with due dates.  Those due dates could be in the past or in the future and the repeats could be daily, monthly or annually and the repeats could have a different number for the repeat such as 1 day, 10 days, 1 month, 3 months, 1 year, 24 months, etc.

I tried using the formula =TODAY()-MOD(TODAY()-B4,E4)+E4 in CELL H4 then changed the number of days in E4 to see if it worked starting with 1 incrementing by 1 to 31 and found that it gave incorrect results with several of the numbers.

Comment: Let me guess: the problem happens when the due date was in the future and was further away than the interval provided? (ex: due date in one month, but interval is 10 days)

Comment: Yes - I was using 10/1/2019 as First Due Date and repeat interval was every X days starting with 1 and going up by 1.

Comment: Thanks for your help!!

Comment: I tried the fix you suggested above...but it still is not working.  I assume the 14 is meant for 14 days?  I have been taking the formula and substituting X for the 14 such that X is 1,2,3,4,5,6,etc. and when X=4 and 5 it shows the same date and 6 and 7 show the same date...so it appears that something is not right.

Comment: Yes, the `14` is for 14 days. I have tested multiple times and cannot reproduce your error